# Fastboot stuck on "Sending 'boot.img'" (TWRP, Moto G7 plus "lake")

Tags: twrp, fastboot, linux, motorola

`fastboot version 30.0.4-6686687`

Trying to temporarily boot TWRP recovery image `twrp-3.4.0-0-lake.img` on my unlocked Motorola `Moto G7 Plus`.

Phone is connected via USB `Type-C to Type-C` cord from the box to my laptop running Linux (`Manjaro 20.0.3`) Live USB system.

When I run `./fastboot boot twrp-3.4.0-0-lake.img` or `./fastboot boot boot.img` (same file, renamed) with and without `sudo`, it always gets stuck at `Sending 'boot.img' (30080 KB)` doing nothing.

`Bootloader logs` section of `fastboot` mode shows `cmd: download:01d60000`.

The PC I use now is the only PC that helped me to actually unlock the bootloader. Other PCs I have were not able to send correct `fastboot` commands (for example, `oem help` transformed to `oem helpersion`, and `oem get_unlock_data` cut to `oem get_unlock`). Those PCs had regular USB `Type-A` `3.0` ports, so I connected them to my phone with corresponding 3rd-party cable. It might be of insufficient quality though.

All files are located near to the root of extrenal SSD connected to another Type-C port, so the absolute paths to `TWRP` image and `fastboot` executable should not be too long.

`Type-C` cords are new and OK.

Motorola doesn't distribute Linux drivers for their devices.

What else could be wrong here? Please help. Any advice is appreciated.

Will update this post later with my own findings as well for people who could stumble a similar problem.

## Update 1

Tried `fastboot boot boot.img` on another PC. It is also running Linux (`Ubuntu 20.04`). Connection is from `Type-A` to `Type-C`. Wire is good. No noticeable changes. Main issue persists.

## Update 2

Was able to perform `fastboot.exe boot boot.img` on another PC under Windows 10. Don't know why it worked. Specs are different than laptops', but cable is the same. Might be a driver issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated version of `platform-tools` works fine. Perhaps this was a bug.

To get latest `platform-tools` you can:

- `git clone --branch sdk-release --single-branch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery` and build it;

  - Check [this repo](https://github.com/anatol/android-platform-tools-build) for some building instructions;
- Download pre-built binary executables at [releases page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools);
- Update package with your distro's package manager:

  - Ubuntu-based: `apt upgrade android-sdk-platform-tools`
  - Arch-based: `pacman -S android-tools`

> **Note**: keep your system up to date too! USB drivers & other system parts could affect functionality of this case.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: connect the phone using a USB hub (even same port) :P

...worked for me.

Source: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/yet-again-fastboot-is-stuck-on-sending-boot-img.4166479/post-86491327

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).